# Supercap liquid heater

Tags: wo2016138968a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2016138968A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2016138968A1)

Will there or are there any independent claims relative to how the supercapacitors are charged in the cited patent application?

Comment: I sincerely doubt there will be any claims about how the supercap is heated as that isn't what the inventor is trying to cover.

Comment: I found prior art that pre-dates the application by 3 years: http://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Super_20Fast_20Kettle

Answer (score 0):

The application has only one independent claim and it doesn't mention how the supercapacitor is charged. While claims can and most often are changed between the application and eventual granted patent, it seems unlikely that a completely new one will be added covering the charging circuit. I'm assuming this is because this isn't what the inventor considers novel. If you are wondering how the charging is accomplished, there is some description in the specification.